# Network connection error- react native using expo cli

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, axios, expo

I'm building an API and react-native application. The server works well (tested with PostMan) but the application doesn't call the server. It blocks when axios has to send the post request.
I also tried to type ip address instead of localhost but it didn't worked as well. (HERE IS MY CODE)

```
 const LoginScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [hidePassword, setHidePassword] = useState(true);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState();
  const [messageType, setMessageType] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = (credentials, setSubmitting) => {
    handleMessage(null);
    const url = "http://192.168.1.110:5000/bankrate/login/login";
    axios
      .post(url, credentials)
      .then((res) => {
        const result = res.data;
        const { message, status, data } = result;

        if (status !== "SUCCESS") {
          handleMessage(message, status);
        } else {
          navigation.navigate("HomeScreen", { ...data[0] });
        }
        setSubmitting(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setSubmitting(false);
        handleMessage(
          "An error occurred! Check your network connection and try again!"
        );
      });
  };
```

Comment: OK, so you built a server program. What we're seeing here is code for a client application that communicates with the server?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using Axios? JavaScript has a nice Fetch API that can do the job: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript's Fetch API instead:

```
const handleSubmit = (credentials,setSubmitting) => {
fetch("http://192.168.1.110:5000/bankrate/login/login", {
method: "post",
headers: { "Content-Type": "insert-mime-type-here (see below)" }
body: // whatever you're sending to the server
}}).then((response) => { if (response.status() === 400) { 
// return either response.json() or response.body() or whatever (see below for details) 
else {
return Promise.reject();
}).then((data) => { // do whatever you want to with the data you get from the server }).catch((error) => // promise rejected);
```

The MIME type you use is the MIME type of whatever you send to the server.

If the server responds with a JSON object, use response.json(), and then data will be a JavaScript object.
If the server responds with anything else, use response.text() and then data will be text.